# Custom trigger to update a webpage using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

To make an example, lets have this psuedo code:

```
$animals = getAnimals(); // getAnimals() gets data from a MySQL table and returns the result as an array
for($i=0; $i<count($animals);$i++) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$animals[$i][0]."</td><td>".$animals[$i][1]."</td></tr>";
```

This would print something like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Cat</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Dog</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now, is there a way for me to update this table without reloading the page? I've looked around and AJAX does this, but I dont know what will trigger it. If I would like to reload using html I would have something like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="30">
```

Or similiar in js, the browser would to this for me. But when using ajax, what can I use to trigger for example every 30 seconds? I've seen examples using POST-data but if I want this to get data from the database on a set interval (and update the html-table), how can I do this in ajax? Is it achievable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   $.post('ajax.php', {data: 'x'}, function(reponse) {
      //Do what you want with response 
   });
}, 30000);
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) is some explanation about this.

Comment: Thanks sir, you're a star!